# slash dot /. What does this mean? Not the easiest google search

Tags: unix

Here is and example of what I'm referring to. The tilde means "/home/usr/", but what does the dot indicate. I know it's not acting as " * " would.

[image: example]

Thanks.

Comment: It's not `/.` + `cpan`, it's `/` + `.cpan` - a directory separator (`/`) and its name `.cpan`. The latter's beginning from full stop sign means that it's hidden.

Comment: In your example, `.cpan` is a hidden folder. See [what are dot-files](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94780/what-are-dot-files).

Comment: I just did a find and as you said it is an actual directory name. Thanks

Comment: It is "an actual directory name" *only* in the sense that it is an alias for its predecessor in the path string (or for the current directory if there is no predecessor). This is an important difference; see my answer.

Comment: The image in the question showing the path in question is now a broken link, but based on comments and answers elsewhere on this page, I think the original path in question was `~/.cpan/`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. "/." pronounced "Slashdot" is [a popular tech news website](http://slashdot.org/).
2. `.` in a UNIX filesystem context is similar to a "no-op"; it is the "identity" path and refers to the immediately preceding directory (or the current directory if there is nothing preceding it). So `/.` is equivalent to `/` and `/home/me/.` is equivalent to `/home/me`. `.` by itself is equivalent to the *current* directory. This has uses in some situations: for example, running `./command` runs a program called `command` *and requires it to be located in the current directory*, bypassing the `PATH`.
3. `.` as a filename *prefix* means a hidden file, as @LaurentB said in his answer; however `.` by itself cannot be the name of a file. Filenames beginning with `.` are not typically shown by `ls` or other directory listing programs unless an option is set to view hidden files.

Answer (score 3):

It indicates a hidden file/folder.
Try to list it with `ls` -> you won't see it.
With `ls -a` you will.

Comment: **This is incorrect.** `.` by itself cannot be used as the name of a file.

Comment: @dvnrrs I don't think that's what he meant.

Comment: @woz I don't think hidden files is what the OP meant; in any case this answer is incomplete without making that distinction.

Comment: @dvnrrs You're right that you can't use a dot by itself (since that indicates the current folder), but you're wrong about this answer being incorrect. Laurent B merely states that files beginning with a dot are hidden.

Answer (score 1):

"~/.cpan/" is a hidden directory ".cpan" in your home directory. "~" is an unix abbreviation for a user's own home directory. ~user_X points to user_X's home directory.